# opencv - crop according to coloured points in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Given an image with say just two coloured points in it.. Is it possible to crop the image from the coordinates of the first colured point to the coordinates of the second coloured point .

[A sample image where i have to crop between two green points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRm9j.jpg)

Comment: Can you show sample image you are working on?

Comment: What color are they ?

Comment: @Jazz added the sample image .

Comment: @Meghana Do you want to crop image from green points?

Comment: @Jazz yes from the green points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, if the colored points have a distinct range of color when compared with the rest of the image.

Algorithm:
1. Convert the image to HSV color space
2. Scan the image while looking for pixels in the range of hue and saturation of the color/s of the points.
3. Record minimum and maximum X,Y coordinates of the points that match.
4. calculate the bounding box of the region using the coordinates.
5. Crop the image using the bounding box.

You can try to follow these steps and edit the question with code if/when you come up with errors. Uploading a sample image somewhere and linking to it will help us provide better answers.